# Scraping table data on webpage in Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data regarding NIL data for college athletes from the following site: https://nilcollegeathletes.com/athletes. I am wanting to grab the name, list of sponsors, school, and sport of each athlete and have it in a tabular table such that, if a player has multiple sponsors, the name, school, and sport appear on each row with each sponsor.

I don't know much about webpages and scraping, but it appears the info on the site is in tables in a table. It seems no matter how I structure the code I can't get it to find and capture the text of the data.

Here is the code I have been using so far. After this section code I was anticipating writing the code for the school and sport info, and then with all of it, creating a Pandas data frame with the info I'm wanting.

With this code below, my thought process was to find all tables on the page, and then loop through each table to grab the info about each athlete. The actual coding of that, though, is what I can't seem to figure out.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import html5lib

urlopen_req = requests.get("https://nilcollegeathletes.com/athletes", 
                      headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}).text

def scrapeDeals(url):
    pd.read_html(urlopen_req, flavor='lxml')[0]['Sponsors'][0]
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen_req, "html.parser")
    
    deals = [i for i in soup.find('table').find_all('tr')]
    
    nildeals = []
    
    for i in deals:
        
        row = []
        
        #Get the name of each player
        col1 = i.find('td')
        row.append(col1.a.text)
            
        #Get a list of the sponsors of the athlete
        col2 = col1.find_next_sibling()

        for j in col2:            
            row.append(col2.li.text)
            nildeals.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)/[`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas.DataFrame.explode) :

```
#for the first page
df = (pd.read_html(urlopen_req, flavor="lxml")[0]
          .assign(Sponsors= lambda x: x["Sponsors"].str.split(r"\s\s+"))
          .explode("Sponsors")
)
```

Output :
​

```
print(df)

              Name                          Sponsors                  University      Sport    Details
0   Jashon Hubbard  614 Chiropractic Barstool Sports   The Ohio State University  Wrestling  More info
0   Jashon Hubbard                    CRMD Ice Cream   The Ohio State University  Wrestling  More info
0   Jashon Hubbard                           Celsius   The Ohio State University  Wrestling  More info
..             ...                               ...                         ...        ...        ...
18  Austin Deculus                     PSD Underwear  Louisiana State University   Football  More info
18  Austin Deculus                       Yoke Gaming  Louisiana State University   Football  More info
19     Spencer Lee                   Barstool Sports          University of Iowa  Wrestling  More info

[44 rows x 5 columns]
```

***Update :***

If you want to retrieve the tables of a range or all the pages, use this :

```
list_dfs = []
​
for page_number in range(1, 6): #replace 6 by 421 if you want all the pages
    urlopen_req = requests.get(f"https://nilcollegeathletes.com/athletes?page={page_number}", 
                      headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}).text
​
    list_dfs.append(pd.read_html(urlopen_req, flavor="lxml")[0].assign(PageNumber= page_number))

df = (pd.concat(list_dfs, ignore_index=True)
          .assign(Sponsors= lambda x: x["Sponsors"].str.split(r"\s\s+"))
          .explode("Sponsors"))
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

              Name                          Sponsors                 University      Sport    Details  PageNumber
0   Jashon Hubbard  614 Chiropractic Barstool Sports  The Ohio State University  Wrestling  More info           1
0   Jashon Hubbard                    CRMD Ice Cream  The Ohio State University  Wrestling  More info           1
0   Jashon Hubbard                           Celsius  The Ohio State University  Wrestling  More info           1
..             ...                               ...                        ...        ...        ...         ...
97      Jaden Pask                   Barstool Sports           Davidson College   Football  More info           5
98    Evan Russell                   Barstool Sports    University of Tennessee   Baseball  More info           5
99      Jake Lynch                   Barstool Sports        Stanford University   Football  More info           5

[143 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I hadn't thought to use that. This works for the first page of results, but will it also work with code to have it go to subsequent webpages to pull the same info from those as well?

Comment: You’re welcome. Yes it’ll work, you just need to put the code in a loop and readjust the link. Let me know if you need some help ;)

Comment: I've been trying for quite a few hours now to get it in a loop, but I'm not having much success unfortunately. 
Here is the last thing I tried, but it still only pulls the first page and doesn't go to the next pages. My thought was, since the a href part only gives the end of the link for the next page, that I would need to build the URL. Do you have any advice?

`
urlbase = "https://nilcollegeathletes.com"
pgadd = soup.find('div', class_="-mt-px flex w-0 flex-1 justify-end").a["href"]
    
 try:
       nextpage = urlbase+pgadd
except:
       nextpage = None
`

Comment: I apologize for the poor formatting of my comment above.

Comment: No worries, I updated my answer earlier today. Can you check it out ?

Comment: What you did makes sense. As I learn more about Python, it's interesting seeing the various ways to accomplish things. I appreciate your help!